# List of different derived objects as ComboBox DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, lambda

My application consists of a winform where boxes can be drawn on top of an image. These boxes have coordinates, a type (all derived classes from a main `FormBox` class) and a possible `group` argument (in generated XML for export).

This group argument is chosen by the user from a ComboBox. Initially, the ComboBox is empty and the user can set a `GroupName` on a box of one type that will populate the ComboBox list for other boxes of the same type, thus allowing them to be grouped together or not.

I now have the need to combine grouping for multiple box types and have been bashing my head against the wall for a way to populate this ComboBox.

For one box type, there's not really a problem:

```
cboUserField_GroupName.DataSource = (from aBox in someFormData.Boxes
where (aBox is UserContentFormBox) select (aBox as UserContentFormBox)).GroupBy(x => x.GroupName).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

cboUserField_GroupName.ValueMember = "GroupName";
```

But since I have two separate lists, each populated with a collection of objects from child classes of `FormBox`, I'd like to bind the ComboBox control to a joined list, whether it be `GroupName` strings or objects is not really important.
This didn't do much, mainly because I couldn't figure out what the value member would be from a simple `List<string>`, additionally because the list ended up being filled with null objects anyway:

```
List<string> groupNames = (from aBox in someFormData.Boxes where (aBox is UserContentFormBox || aBox is VATReturnFormBox) select aBox.GroupName).Distinct().ToList();

cboUserField_GroupName.DataSource = groupNames.ToList();
```

So, in short, how do I bind a ComboBox control to a list, filled (by means of lambda) with objects derived from a base class? The binding should be on the `GroupName` property.

Should I bring back each list to a `List<FormBox>`, that can be easily joined? Are there other, better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found it.
First, make two `List<string>` of the object `GroupName` properties:

```
List<string> firstList = (from aBox in someFormData.Boxes
where (aBox is UserContentFormBox)
select (aBox as UserContentFormBox).GroupName).Distinct().ToList();

List<string> secondList = (from aBox in someFormData.Boxes
where (aBox is VATReturnFormBox)
select (aBox as VATReturnFormBox).GroupName).Distinct().ToList();
```

Then, join those lists, removing nulls and duplicates, sort and populate a new list:

```
List<string> groupNames = firstList.Union(secondList).Where(x => x != null).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

Finally, fill the necessary ComboBoxes with the values:

```
cboUserField_GroupName.Items.AddRange(groupNames.ToArray());
cboVATReturn_GroupName.Items.AddRange(groupNames.ToArray());
```

Thanks anyway.